# Custom UI for main window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I need a help to start learning in a new area. I've been doing C# programming for some time now, and I've  created some complex GUI and applications. What I don't know is how some programmers manage to create this type of main windows for c# applications, for example:

[image: Example]

Or:

[image]

Or this:[image]

Let's say that I do the design in photoshop or something - then how can i change the main window of the c# application so drastically that it will look like this? A friend of mine told me about WPF and c# User Control, but as far as I've seen browsing through WPF sites, I couldn't find something like I want to do.

Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those may look nice at first but it usually just becomes annoying...

Comment: @H.B.: I second that. Think very carefully before you throw out all the design elements people are used to!

Comment: I am posting this as a comment instead of an answer because I'm just providing you a link.  I think this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19213/An-Alpha-Channel-Composited-Windows-Form-with-Desi) is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like that in WPF. It is very powerful, but you'll need some design skills to get something looking as good as your last example.

Look for some WPF tutorials and/or books (I found WPF Unleashed to be really good). Also you might look into using Blend for the design part.